# Мерж одинаковых значений массива сохраняя значения первого и последнего ключа элемента массива

Tags: php, массивы, алгоритм, структуры-данных

Всем привет!

Имеется массив графика работы заведения, где ключ - порядковый номер дня недели:

```
Array(
    0 => 09:15-18-00,
    1 => 09:15-18-00,
    ...
    ...
);
```

И массив дней недели:

```
$arDays = Array('Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб', 'Вс');
```

Задача сводится к тому, что бы распределить все одинаковые значения в подмассивы и выходные вынести в отдельный подмассив и итоге выводит в верстку по следующему шаблону:

Будни:
Пн-Ср: 09:15-18-00
Чт-Пт: 10:00-19:00
Выходные:
Сб-Вс: 11:00-16:30

Максимум, что смог сделать, так это разбить одинаковые значения в подмассивы.

[Вот что получилось](http://pastebin.com/0tFJfQZN)

Если у кого-то найдется время помочь - буду безмерно благодарен!

Comment: Так много записей, что руками нельзя разбить массив ?

Comment: Bastian, изначально спроектировано неудобно. И  да, записей очень много.